# Reconstructing a macro from its \meaning in tex-core

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, meaning

In order to gain a deeper understanding of TeX I am following [this guide on TeX Programming](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf).
It contains examples on macro expansion like this one

```tex
\def\point(#1,#2){we do something with #1 and #2}
\def\temp{(42,1234)}
\expandafter\point\temp
```

which got me tinkering with tring to reconstruct a macro from it's definition.

Here is my approach:

```
% definition of macro
\def\macro #1{I am a macro called with #1}
% storing it in toks1
\toks1={\meaning\macro}

% define reconstruction of arguments/pattern from \meaning
\def\args #1:#2->#3{#2}%
% define reconstruction of definition from \meaning
\def\definition #1:#2->#3{#3}%

% define reconstruction itself
\def\reconstruct(#1,#2){\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname \args #2 {\definition #2}}%

% reconstruct contents of toks1
\reconstruct(reconstructed,\expandafter\expandafter\null\the\toks1)
% print its meaning
\message{\meaning\reconstructed}


\end
```

this however does not result in the macro that I want to be reconstructed.
I can't use it in the intended way, nor does it's \meaning mirror the original macro.

I tried  various different placements for \expandafter, but this was ultimately the most logical way to do it (for me at least).

what is the proper way to do this using TeX only?

I think that the expansion as done above will result in something like this

```
\def\mymacoro #1{\def\mymacro2 #1{#1}}
```

wich is obvioulsy a problem;
can I help myself with a group there or are # registers not shadowed?

Comment: you can do simple cases (you'll need `\scantokens` to reparse the string) but it is not possible to do this in general, for example you can not reliably determine any delimited arguments that the macro may have from `\meaning` (or anything else)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with you approach. You should first store the meaning, not `\meaning\macro`, so

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\meaning\macro}
```

(scratch registers with odd number should be reserved for global assignments, but it's a minor point). Now, `\showthe\toks0` will print

```
> macro:#1->I am a macro called with #1.
```

but you'll *never* be able to reconstruct `\macro` from this data unless you write the result in a file and read it or, equivalently, use `\scantokens` that's only available with e-TeX engines (so not with Knuth TeX).

The problem is that the result of `\meaning\macro` is composed of category 12 character tokens (but spaces have category code 10).

This works for macros with undelimited arguments (with limitations on the replacement texts, which must not contain `\replacement`).

It *might* also work with delimited arguments.

```
\newwrite\reconstructout
\newread\reconstructin

\def\macro #1{I am a macro called with #1}

\immediate\openout\reconstructout=\jobname.rcn
\immediate\write\reconstructout{\meaning\macro}
\immediate\closeout\reconstructout
\openin\reconstructin=\jobname.rcn
\chardef\remember=\endlinechar
\endlinechar=-1
\read\reconstructin to \reconstruct
\closein\reconstructin
\endlinechar=\remember

\def\args #1:#2->#3\args{#2}
\def\replacement #1:#2->#3\replacement{#3}

\toks0=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\args\reconstruct\args}
\toks2=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\replacement\reconstruct\replacement}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\mymacro\the\toks0{\the\toks2}%
}\x

\ifx\mymacro\macro\message{SUCCESS!!!}\fi
```

Here's the console output:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=tex)
(./reconstruct.tex SUCCESS!!!)
```

It also works if you do

```
\def\point(#1,#2){we do something with #1 and #2}
```

and replace `\macro` in the code above with `\point`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\def\macro #1{I am a macro called with #1}
% storing it in toks1
\toks1={\meaning\macro}
```

at this point `toks1` contains the two tokens `\meaning\macro` I think you wanted it to hold the string from `\meaning` which would be

```
\toks1=\expandafter{\meaning\macro}
```

Note however that `\meaning` is a "verbatim" string everything is catcode 12 (punctuation) or 10 (space)  so in particular the letters in the text are not catcode 11 (letter) and the `#` in `#1` is a normal puctuation `#` like `\#` not the macro parameter.

In classical TeX to reparse this string assuming normal catcodes you could write it out to a file and then read it back, e-tex offers `\scantokens` to reparse (internally it does more or less exactly the same as a file write followed by a file read).

Similarly

```
\expandafter\expandafter\null\the\toks1
```

The first `\expandafter` expands `\null` so

```
\expandafter\hbox{}\the\toks1
```

so the second `\expandafter` expands `{` which is not expandable so this is

```
\hbox{}\the\toks1
```

which is not what you intended. (It isn't clear what you wanted to do with `\null` in any case it adds a box which is not wanted)

Comment: I was under the impression that `\null` would be expanded to nothing and thus when used with `\expandafter` would simply expand the second argument without putting anything in front afterwards; thanks for the pointer that it expands to `\hbox{}` this clears up a lot of things for me

Comment: @FabianSchneider `\empty` expands to nothing, but `\expandafter\expandafter\empty\the\toks1` is `\expandafter\the\toks1` after the first expandafter so the second expandafter would apply to `\toks` which isn't expandable so is `\the\toks1`

Answer (score 1):

For gaining **deeper understanding** of TeX I recommend reading the TeXbook, being very picky about the context of every word while reading and strictly sticking to correctly using the terminology introduced in that book.

The [guide of programming referenced by you](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf) uses its own home-brewed terminology which lacks of precision and therefore may be misleading for novices.

E.g., you find explanations like

[image]

But neither is explained what "contents" in the phrase "contents of a macro" means, nor is explained what "as it is seen by TeX" means.

Besides this, applying `\meaning` actually is not restricted to macros. `\meaning` can be applied to a *⟨token⟩* which is not a *⟨macro⟩* as well:  You can use `\meaning` for finding out about the meanings of primitives, explicit character-tokens, implicit character-tokens, `\chardef`-tokens, `\toksdef`-tokens, `\dimendef` -tokens, whatsoever `\...def`-tokens, ...

A novice cannot deduce that characters occurring in the .tex-input-file may have been discarded at the time of tokenizing the definition of the macro whose `\meaning` is to be delivered because at that time those characters were of category code 10(space) and thus got discarded in moments where the reading-apparatus was in state S(skipping blanks) or N(new line).

A novice cannot deduce that `\meaning` just delivers a sequence of explicit character-tokens of category 12(other) with spaces being the only exception: Spaces will be of category 10(space). I.e., `\meaning` does not give you clues which of the character-tokens it delivers come from control-word-tokens or control-symbol-tokens and which of the character-tokens it delivers come from explicit character-tokens. Besides this, with explicit character-tokens you loose information about categories. Routines for patching macros that are based on `\meaning` actually just do some sort of "very educated guessing".

A novice cannot deduce that the result of `\meaning` is affected by the value of the integer-parameter `\escapechar`.

A novice cannot deduce that the result of `\meaning` may be affected by category codes that are current at the time of carrying out `\meaning`: When `\meaning` delivers the symbolic representation of a control-symbol-token, no space-token is appended. When `\meaning` delivers the symbolic representation of a control-word-token, a space-token is appended. Whether a control-sequence-token whose name consists of a single character is treated as a control-symbol-token or as control-word-token depends on the category-code of that character current at the time of carrying out `\meaning`:

```tex
\def\test{\z\z W\z}
\tt
\string\test=\meaning\test

\catcode`\z=12
\string\test=\meaning\test

\escapechar=`\A
\catcode`\z=11
\string\test=\meaning\test

\catcode`\z=12
\string\test=\meaning\test

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\escapechar=`\\
\catcode`\z=11
\def\testA{\z\zW \z}
\def\testB{\z\z W \z}
\catcode`\z=12
\string\testA=\meaning\testA

\string\testB=\meaning\testB

meanings are \ifx\testA\testB equal\else different\fi

\bye
```

[image]

TeXbook, Chapter 7: How TeX Reads What You Type   clearly says:

> In the examples so far, `\string` has converted control sequences into lists of tokens that begin with `\12` . But this backslash token isn't really hardwired into TeX; **there’s a parameter called `\escapechar` that specifies what character should be used when control sequences are output as text.** The value of `\escapechar` is normally TeX’s internal code for backslash, but it can be changed if another convention is desired.

*This paragraph is a nice example on why I suggest being very picky while reading the book: Although in the beginning the paragraph is about `\string` it is not said that `\string` is the only routine where outputting control sequences as text plays a rôle.

`\meaning`, too, is such a routine.*

TeXbook, Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros) clearly says:

> `\meaning⟨token⟩`. TeX expands this to the sequence of characters that would be displayed on your terminal by the commands ‘`\let\test=⟨token⟩ \show\test`’. For example, ‘`\meaning A`’ usually expands to ‘`the letter A`’; ‘`\meaning\A`’ after ‘`\def\A#1B{\C}`’ expands to ‘`macro:#1B->\C` ’.
> [...]
> In all of the cases listed so far, `\the` produces a result that is a sequence of ASCII character tokens. **Category code 12 (“other”) is assigned to each token, except that character code 32 gets category 10 (“space”).** The same rule is used to assign category codes to the tokens produced by `\number`, `\romannumeral`, `\string`, `\meaning`, `\jobname`, and `\fontname`.

TeXbook, Chapter 21: Making Boxes clearly says:

> Each `\write` command produces output in **the form that TeX always uses to display token lists symbolically: Characters represent themselves (except that you get duplicated characters like `##` for macro parameter characters); unexpandable control sequence tokens produce their names, preceded by the `\escapechar` and followed by a space (unless the name is an active character or a control sequence formed from a single nonletter)**.

*Another example where pickiness while reading is a good thing: Although in the beginning the paragraph is about `\write` it is not said that `\write` is the only routine where displaying token lists symbolically  plays a rôle.

`\meaning`, too, is such a routine.

`\meaning`, however, does not duplicate macro-parameter-characters.

Perhaps the word "except" is intended to indicate that this duplication is a deviation of the form of displaying token-lists symbolically which occurs when using `\write` for writing things (to text-file or terminal).*

Comment: these examples do help understanding the book and terminology a bit better, thanks for the detailed explanation and examples :)